# Is there a term that means "oft-used misquotation"?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology, quotations

There are some quotations that people always seem to get wrong:

> Alas, poor Yorick, I knew him well. [Real quote from *Hamlet*: "Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him, Horatio."]
>
> I have nothing to offer but blood, sweat and tears. [Real quote from Churchill:  "I have nothing to offer but blood, toil, tears and sweat."]
>
> Reports of my death have been greatly exaggerated.* [Real quote from Mark Twain: "The report of my death is an exaggeration."]

I keep thinking there is a term for this, the way *malapropism* is a term for a misused word. I have the feeling I read the word somewhere, but all the Googling I've done doesn't give it up.

[*] *This one is particularly galling to me, since Twain was such a master of understatement. Oh well ...*

Comment: There is a word for an altered/changed quote, which these seem to be. I can't remember it unfortunately!

Comment: Wikiquote has a nice list of them... http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/List_of_misquotations

Comment: @Andy: Andrew Grimm's answer below to TVTropes has an even longer list: [Beam me up, Scotty!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeamMeUpScotty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I can come up with are just plain *misquotation* and *corruption.* How dull.

Comment: Dull, but accurate. As accurate as it gets I think.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I'm going to accept this while wistfully hoping some white knight will ride in and save the day with the exact word I think must exist somewhere out there. Otherwise I may have to coin one myself. But that will have to wait for inspiration ...

Answer (score 0):

TV Tropes gives [Beam me up, Scotty!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeamMeUpScotty)